# how voice recognition in android works?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I want to know that how voice recognition in android works? Which library it uses for voice recognition? Does it perform voice recognition process on device/mobile it self or it sends all voice to google servers and receives text in responce?

Thanks,
  Sunny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at <s>[4 Feets.com](http://www.4feets.com/2009/04/speech-recognition-in-android-sdk-15/)</s> [4 Feets.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119102047/http://www.4feets.com/2009/04/speech-recognition-in-android-sdk-15/)

They have a nice overview with a little example regarding voice reg in SDK 1.5.

Comment: Thanks Kowkiebox, Can u please tell me that Can I do speech recognition on android without internet connection? My port of android will be on device without internet connection.

Comment: I have not done something like this or know if it could work. The following is a quote from "http://androidandme.com/2009/05/news/cupcake-voice-recognition-now-available-for-testing/".Note that the processing is not CPU intensive on the phone, but it will need to be sent to Google to be turned into text (thanks to Tim H for pointing this out on the last article). You’ll need a good internet connection for this. I found EDGE (non-3G data connection) to be a bit unreliable.

Comment: Try these, seems project is dead. https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition https://cloud.google.com/speech/

Answer (score 7):

The 4 Feets.com answer is now very misleading, as the link contains quite a bit of speculative information that turned out to be inaccurate.

Please checkout the [VoiceRecognition.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) demo in ApiDemos, and the RecognizerIntent reference.  Android speech recognition requires an internet connection as the data is sent off to google and you receive a list of possible text translations back.