# Audio Input on Android Emulator

Tags: android, voice-recognition

How can one get audio input on the Android Emulator?  I'm using the 2.2 SDK, and emulating on Ubuntu 10.10.

I have the hw.audioinput property set to yes on my emulator, but I get the message "Recognizer not present" when I run the Voice Recognition API demo app on the emulator.  On my phone, of course, it works fine.

I'm trying to use the speech input stuff from the SDK as mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html.  They don't mention a thing about getting it to work on the emulator.

I've seen postings all over the forums about this with little to no sure solutions or successes.  You know how it goes with forums.  That's why I'm posting this question to StackOverflow; hopefully we can get one clear-cut answer!

Answer (score 3):

Voice Recognition is handled with an application. The emulator doesn't come with this .apk pre-installed. If you can get Voice.apk from your device and install it in your emulator you might then have it. Check out this post also:

[how voice recognition in android works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380981/how-voice-recognition-in-android-works)

Answer (score 0):

You might need a virtual SD card?  [See this discussion here about it.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/860b5f346c59f2ca/b94fa1131077321f?lnk=gst&q=microphone+emulator#b94fa1131077321f)